# Is it sunnah to clean one's plate after eating?

Tags: sunnah, food

Is it sunnah of Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) to clean one's plate after eating by licking it with fingers or tongue?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's sunnah.

Hadhrat Jabir Radhiallahu ta'ala 'anhu reported:

> I heard from Rasulullah Sallallahu 'Alahihi wasallam that The Satan is
>   present with any one of you in everything he does; he is present even
>   when he eats food; so if any one of you drops a mouthful he should
>   remove away anything filthy on it and eat it and not leave for the
>   devil; and when he finishes (food) he should **lick his fingers**, for he
>   does not know **in what portion of his food the blessing lies**
>
> **Hadith No-177**
>
> **Kitab Al-Ashrabah**
>
> **Sahih Muslim**

And That's why it is sunnah to clean the plate as you don't know in what portion of your food has the Barakah.